# How can we combine two different resources metrics using MQL in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

These are two metrics from the same resource that is **k8s_node** and ** metrics** are :
1: **kubernetes.io/node/cpu/allocatable_utilization**
2: **kubernetes.io/node/cpu/allocatable_cores**

Another metric from the another resources that is **k8s_container** and metric is **kubernetes.io/container/cpu/request_utilization**

Now how can we join these three metric from different resources.